# Issues with $location in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, angularjs

I have a single page app '(Backend in Python/Django)' where my functions return json response and that json response handled by angular js in front end . I am using angular ajax call to hit the function. Now we all know that on ajax call url in address bar do not get changed. But in angular js we can set url using `$location.path()`. So it keeps the history of url I have visited and on browser back button it changes the url in address bar to previous one . But it do not change the content of the page.

My angular ajax call :

```
 app.controller('myController',
    function($scope,$http, $location, $route, $timeout){

        $scope.formData={}

        $scope.getAllBrainframes=function(id){
            if(id){
                $scope.url = '/get-brainframe/'+id+'/'; 
            }else{
               $scope.url = '/get-brainframe/';
            }

            $http.post($scope.url)
                .success(function(data,status){
                   .success(function(data,status){
                   $scope.title = data[0].title
                   $scope.brainframes = data;
                   $location.path($scope.url);
                   $scope.parent= data[0].id;
                })
                .error(function(data,status){
                });

        }
});
```

As I am setting `$location.path()` on ajax success , so it appends the current visited url in address bar and keeps history of every url i have visited. But when I click on browser back button it changes the url in address bar to previous one but not the content.

Now is there any function that i can trigger when I click on browser back button or how I can change the content of page ?

**EDIT :** 
above ajax success function edited .

**My html :**

```
<div class="content">
        <span ng-repeat="brainframe in brainframes">
            <p ng-if = "brainframe.brainframes.length > 0 ">
                <ul class="list-group col-md-5">
                    <div data-ng-repeat="brain in brainframe.brainframes" class="child-brainframes">
                        <a class="my-title" ng-click="getAllBrainframes(brain.brainframe_child.pk)">
                         <li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">{$ brain.count_children $}</span>{$ brain.brainframe_child.title $}</li>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                </ul>
            </p>
            <p ng-if = "brainframe.brainframes.length < 1 ">
                 <span>No brainframes are available.</span>
            </p>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: try using $routeParams to check for id and show different content in the page

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at `$routeParams` and change the content in the template.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qabuza#/home)**

```
.controller("MainCtrl",
   function($scope,$http, $location, $route, $timeout, $routeParams){

   $scope.formData={};

  $scope.id = $routeParams.id;

        $scope.getAllBrainframes=function(id){
            if(id){
                $scope.url = '/home/'+id+'/'; 
            }else{
               $scope.url = '/home';
            }
          console.log($scope.url);
            $location.path($scope.url);
        };

});
```

In your template:

Check for the `$scope` property and show/hide

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="Home.html">
   <p>This is one template</p>

   <p ng-if="id">This is in next template</p>

   <a ng-click="getAllBrainframes('1')">next template</a>
 </script>
```

[Check full code here](http://jsbin.com/qabuza/1/edit?html,js,output)

UPDATED:

If you want to persist the ajax call data between routes, you need to probably store it in a service and access it in your controller based on the `$routeParams` from the service.

Comment: @mohammedrias In my case that ajax call is important and response of that call is passed to html so that i can display my data . I have edit my question please check and let me know if your idea is still possible or not .

Comment: Each time the route changes the controller will be reloaded

Comment: You must store the data of ajax call in a service and then try to access it in the contrller

Comment: route is changing when I click browser back button but controller is not getting reloaded

Comment: The controller will be reloaded each time the route changes. Try putting a console.log message and see it urself. Each time the route changes, the route provider runs and checks which controller/template need to be loaded

Comment: I am using Python/Django as backend and here we can't access tempaltes directly as we do in php `(example.com/test.html)` . So in $routeProvider templateUrl will not work . And if I place my html in ng-template then its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73407/discussion-between-n-imp-and-mohamedrias).